# Using the WinRT search in a Windows Service

Tags: windows, search, windows-runtime, contract

I am a C# sharp developer and have a need to do some searching in Windows 8 from a Windows Service. Is it possible to search apps, settings and files and other search contract registered providers from a normal Windows Service?

How would I go about doing this, what namespaces should I look into etc? I am struggling to bridge WinRT with the rest of Windows here.

Comment: if your app is going to be distributed through the Windows Store, you won't be able to do this, since it won't achieve certification. You'd need to host a service on a publically accessible endpoint.

Comment: This does not need to be distributed through the Windows Store.